# how can I convert a java based annotation maven project to spring boot?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

how can I convert a java based annotation spring mvc maven project to spring boot? I do not have xml file, instead I have a used webconfig class and webinitializer class. I know how to convert a xml based project to spring boot. you might think what is the difference? the difference for me is like I said I have used webconfig class and webinitializer, my spring mvc maven project does not have main class. In which one of these classes should I add: @SpringbootApplication, 
SpringApplication.run(***?what class name comes here?***.class, args);

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) and add the Web dependency. This generates a sample project which should help move you along. There is a lot of coding by convention and annotations with Spring Boot and it comes with a learning curve. [Spring Boot Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/)

**SpringApplication Example from Initializr**

```java
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is my problem, my Spring mvc project does not have  the above main, instead it has WebConfig class and WebInitializer class, in other words, it is java based annotaion project rather than xml. project, I know I have to change the pom.xml and also do some change in main class. since I do not have main class, should I change WebConfig class and WebInitializer class?  there any way to it without writing the project all over again in spring boot?

Comment: If your goal is to run spring boot, you will need to do some updates, but most of the files should remain the same as spring boot web has spring mvc. Here is a migration guide. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-migration